# WinForm scaling incorrectly for some users

Tags: winforms, controls, scale, autoscaling, autoscalemode

I've written a program that I've used and have tested it on xp, win7 and win 10 with various resolutions. 
The main form displays correctly with the controls properly spaced as follows:
[Correctly Scaled Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLxXE.png) 
However, when submitting it for review, the forms do not scale for the tester's system. The controls are overlapping and get cut off by the form edges and looks like this: 
[Incorrectly Scaled Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJCK0.png)

The form is designed to resize and adjust the controls which all works perfectly on any system I test, I have tried changing the "autoscalemode" to "font" or "off" but nothing changes how it loads on the testers system.

I have submitted other programs that have not had this issue so I am at a loss as to what it could be.

Comment: You app is not DpiAware. Start from this: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/7444103), then read this: [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms) and [High DPI Desktop Application Development on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows)